# Using PyQGIS to iterate through layers with custom layout

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layouts, iteration, qgis-python-console

How do I select the layer and apply a layout for export to .PNG?

I use: QGIS 3.34 and the Python Console.

So the manual process is: select layer => go to Layout Manager => Select Layout => Export to PNG. I like to replicate this with Python.

This code works, but the layer doesn't change (it uses the manually selected layer). The legend inside the Layout Manager does change though.

```
import os
project_instance = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project_instance.layoutManager()
layers = project_instance.mapLayers()

for layer in layers.values():
    layerType = layer.type()
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        layer.startEditing()
        iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        layout = manager.layoutByName('Maps_' + layer.name()[11:])
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        outpath = os.path.join(project_instance.homePath(), layout.name() + ".png")
        exporter.exportToImage(outpath, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this [Cheat Sheet](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#layers)

To actually get the layer selected the code is a little more complicated:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
node = root.findLayer(layer.id())
new_state = Qt.Checked if node.isVisible() == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
node.setItemVisibilityChecked(new_state)
```

I use this sample code twice, once to unselect everything and the second time to select one layer, the resulting code is:

```
import os
project_instance = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project_instance.layoutManager()
layers = project_instance.mapLayers()

for layer in layers.values():
   for l in layers.values():
       root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
       node = root.findLayer(l.id())
       new_state = Qt.Unchecked if node.isVisible() == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
       node.setItemVisibilityChecked(new_state)
    layerType = layer.type()
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        node = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        new_state = Qt.Checked if node.isVisible() == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
        node.setItemVisibilityChecked(new_state)
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        layout = manager.layoutByName('Maps_' + layer.name()[11:])
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        outpath = os.path.join(project_instance.homePath(), layout.name() + ".png")
        exporter.exportToImage(outpath, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```